# How does the bracket operator work in pandas when calculating conditional probabilities?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-operator

I was studying ThinkBayes2 and the example it gives contains code that looks like this:
`selected = democrat[liberal]`
all three variables are pandas Series contain boolean type. I've never seen any operator or used it before, So was wondering if anyone can show me how it works here...

```
a = pd.Series([1, 0, 1])
b = pd.Series([1, 2, 0])
a, b, a[b], b[a]
```

And the outcome:

```
(0    1
 1    0
 2    1
 dtype: int64,
 0    1
 1    2
 2    0
 dtype: int64,
 1    0
 2    1
 0    1
 dtype: int64,
 1    2
 0    1
 1    2
 dtype: int64)
```

Couldn't figure out what's going on here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing "conditional" or "boolean" going on here, just normal pandas-fashion indexing .

Since `b` is conceptually `[1, 2, 0]`, `a[b]` is going to retrieve the content of `a` but using `b` as indexes, and in that order.

In other words, `a[b]` is going to retrieve `a[1], a[2], a[0]`, and is equivalent to `a[[1, 2, 0]]`.

Maybe it will be easier to spot if `a` contains letters:

```
a = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = pd.Series([1, 2, 0])
print(a[b])
```

outputs

```
1    b
2    c
0    a
```

And one step simpler, the non-pandas equivalent is

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 0]
print([a[index] for index in b])
```

```
['b', 'c', 'a']
```